# Move files in sequence-Bash/Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to move my files from one directory to SFTP and further to another directory in sequence not together.

Let's say if my directories are `DirA` and `DirB`.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -R /usr/sap/tmp/DirA/. /usr/sap/tmp/DirB/
lftp <<_EOF_
open sftp://User:Password@Host -p Port
lcd /usr/sap/tmp/DirA
cd /
pwd
mput -E /usr/sap/tmp/DirA/*.dat
exit
_EOF_
```

This works fine. But the only problem is it moves all files together at the same time from `dirA` to SFTP. How can I get it to move files one by one (in sequence, say the files moved to SFTP should have at least difference of one second between them)?

Comment: Instead of giving SFTP a wildcard that copies all files at once, create your own loop that invokes SFTP once per file, pausing between instances. You might want to consider using `scp` instead of `sftp` if you can, as it's far easier to work with in a script

Comment: and what's wrong to put all at once?

Comment: ^^^Ditto. Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: If possible, I'd probably use `rsync` instead of *both* `cp` and `lftp` here so it wouldn't copy or transfer unchanged files at all.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?